# A nested fragment is not displayed inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

[image: ViewPager with 3 pages]

The attached picture shows a ViewPager with 3 pages. Each page is implemented as a Fragment. The Toolbar has a + icon in black for adding a new patient. When the + icon is pressed, a nested fragment should be created inside the Patients page which allows the creation of a new patient.

In the Logcat, I can see that the fragment lifecycle callbacks for the nested fragment are called right upto `onResume()`, but the view for the nested fragment is not rendered.

I am doing this to create the nested fragment and insert it into the parent fragment view hierarchy:

```
FrPatientDetails frChild = new FrPatientDetails();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.flPatientsPage, frChild);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

`R.id.flPatientsPage` is a `FrameLayout` in the Patients page into which I am trying to insert the nested fragment.

I am getting a feeling that the way to insert a child fragment into a parent fragment hosted in a `ViewPager` might be different, but I am not clear what to do.

Would someone be able to help here.

Update: Added the xml for the Patients page (parent)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/patients_page_linear_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvHomeViewPatientsPage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/tvEmpty"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
   android:text="@string/patients_page_empty"
   android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textSize="16sp"
    />
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/flPatientsPage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Update: This is the screenshot after following what @Filo suggested:
[image: Child fragment view superimposed on the parent fragment]

Comment: Did you try with `add` instead of `replace`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried `add` and `repalce` and both give the same result.

Comment: does the plus sign adds a nested fragment relevant to the fragment which is at the display

Comment: Clicking the plus sign causes the code snippet above to be executed.

Comment: Maybe a problem related to your xml, with the `flPatientsPage` framelayout. Could you post your layout for the parent fragment, please?

Comment: I have uploaded the xml in the main description

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, here is the problem that I was facing:
 There is an Activity A containing a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager(V)`. V contains 3 pages (fragments). One of the fragments(F1) contains a child fragment C. I was able to display F1. I was unable to display C when the user clicked a button in F1.

Solution: V used a FragmentPagerAdapter to setup the fragments. Inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`, do **not** launch F1 directly. Instead, launch a a fragment called F1Wrapper which contains a `FrameLayout`. Inside `F1Wrapper.onCreateView()`, create a `FragmentTransaction` adding F1 to the backstack. Use `getChildFragmentManager` to create the transaction. Pass the FrameLayout of F1Wrapper as the view container for F1.

When the user clicks the button in F1 to launch fragment C, create a `FragmentTransaction.replace()` in F1Wrapper which adds C to the backstack. Use `getChildFragmentManager` to create the transaction. Again, pass the FrameLayout of F1Wrapper as the view container for C. C will now replace F1 in the backstack and will be displayed.

Note: You **cannot** pass the ViewPager as the view container for C. That is the crux of the problem and the main reason why we need to use a wrapper fragment. If you pass V as the view container for C, C.onCreateView() will crash.